# MS Access Join Query with WHERE condition

Tags: ms-access, inner-join, where-clause

I am using MS Access 2010 and struggling with the following query. Say I have two tables, tblWeeklyData and tblMainData which both contain information about students and their classes. The records in each table are linked by the common key fldStudentNumber. Suppose both tables also contain field fldClass which holds the name of Class the student is taking.

tblWeeklyData holds new student information and is compared with tblMainData to identify only existing students that are studying new classes.

I wish to query the two tables to identify students in tblWeeklyData that already exist in tblMainData (matching on StudentNumber) and which are studying a new class i.e. there is no match between tblWeeklyData.fldClass and tblMainData.fldClass for that particular student.

[Edit] New students within tblWeeklyData that do not have a matching StudentNumber in tblMainData should not be returned by the query.[/Edit]

The SQL I am using is:

```
SELECT [tblWeeklyData].fldStudentNumber, [tblWeeklyData].fldClass
FROM tblWeeklyData INNER JOIN tblMainData ON   
([tblWeeklyData].fldStudentNumber = tblMainData.fldStudentNumber)
WHERE ((([tblWeeklyData].fldClass)<>[tblMainData].[fldClass]));
```

If tblWeeklyData contains rows

```
fldStudentNumber fldClass
A0001            Chemistry
```

and tblMainData contains

```
fldStudentNumber fldClass
A0001            Art
A0001            Biology
```

The above query correctly returns from tblWeeklyData existing student A0001 studying the new class Chemistry:

```
fldStudentNumber fldClass
A0001            Chemistry
```

However, this query does not work with the following data:

```
tblWeeklyData
-------------
fldStudentNumber fldClass
A0001            Chemistry
A0001            Dentistry

blMainData
----------
fldStudentNumber fldClass
A0001            Art
A0001            Biology
A0001            Chemistry
```

I would like the query to only return "A0001 Dentistry" from tblWeeklyData as Dentistry is the only *new" class that existing student A0001 is studying. However, the query returns:

```
fldStudentNumber fldClass
A0001            Chemistry
A0001            Dentistry
```

I do not want row "A0001 Chemistry" to be returned as Chemistry is not a new class for student A0001 with it already existing in tblMainData.

[Edit]To demonstrate that new students should not be returned, suppose there are two tables

```
tblWeeklyData
-------------
fldStudentNumber fldClass
A0001            Chemistry
A0001            Dentistry
A0002            Zoology

blMainData
----------
fldStudentNumber fldClass
A0001            Art
A0001            Biology
A0001            Chemistry
```

Here, student A002 should not be returned as it does not exist in tblMainData. Is this possible?

[/Edit]

I have tried many variations of the above query with no success. I can see in the last example that the WHERE clause evaluates to true with "Chemistry <> Art" or "Chemistry <> Biology" so I need a different WHERE condition that will look at *every" class a given student is studying to determine if a class is new. I have looked at SQL EXISTS IN and subqueries but I have not yet been able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The `WHERE` doesn't work because it only compare values of the *same* row and you need to compare each value of the first table with each value of the second table but without combining both tables.

If you are doing it for only one student each time you can use `IN`:

```
SELECT fldStudentNumber, fldClass
FROM tblWeeklyData
WHERE fldStudentNumber='A0001'
  AND fldClass NOT IN (SELECT fldClass FROM tblMainData WHERE fldStudentNumber='A0001')
```

If you need to do it for several students at the same time or have more than one condition then you need to user `EXISTS` instead:

```
SELECT fldStudentNumber, fldClass
FROM tblWeeklyData
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblMainData
   WHERE tblMainData.fldStudentNumber=tblWeeklyData.fldStudentNumber
     AND tblMainData.fldClass=tblWeeklyData.fldClass)
```

Comment: Thank you Alberto - your provided solution works perfectly, However, I see that my initial framing of the question was too simplified and did not state that only students existing in both tables should be returned. If for example, a new student is present in tblWeeklyData that does not have a matching StudentNumber in tblMainData, it should not be returned. I will go to my initial post and edit it to explain further what I mean,